# Creating Powershell scripts to enhance user entry

Tags: powershell

Caller to a payment line enters 4 digit expiry date MMYY, but I need to make sure this is a valid date in the future.

I have tried get-date but I need to make sure the 4 digit number is converted to a date format before checking against Get-Date Uformat MMyy.

Any Help would be greatfull

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `[DateTime]::ParseExact`

```
$monthYear = "0524"

try {
  if ([DateTime]::ParseExact($monthYear,'MMyy', $null) -gt $(get-date)) {
    Write-Output "valid date in the future" 
  } else {
    Write-Output "valid date in the past"
  }
}
catch {
    Write-Output "invalid date"
}
```

Change `$monthYear` to validate the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
$read = read-host enter date in the future in format MMYY
try{
    $month = [int]($read[0..1] -join "")
    $year = [int]($read[2..3] -join "")
    $date = get-date -Month $month -Year "20$year"
    if(((get-date) - $date) -le 0){
        write-host "You have entered a valid date in the future: $date" -ForegroundColor Green
    }else{
        Write-Error Not a valid Date 
    }
}catch{
    write-host you have entered an invalid date -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2-cents using `[DateTime]::TryParseExact()`:

```
$mmyy = "0524"   # user input

$checkDate = (Get-Date).Date
$thisMonth = (Get-Date -Year $checkDate.Year -Month $checkDate.Month -Day 1).Date
if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($mmyy, 'MMyy', $null, 'None', [ref]$checkDate)) {
    # [math]::Sign() returns -1 for a negative value, +1 for a positive value or 0 if the value is 0 
    switch ([math]::Sign(($checkDate - $thisMonth).Ticks)) {
        -1 { "$checkDate is in the past" }
         1 { "$checkDate is in the future" }
        default {  "$checkDate is this month" }
    }
}
else {
    write-host "Invalid date" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```